# passing just the index clicked to the prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component rendering a list of roles when i click edit i only want my selected index to pass through to show with the child component pop up

currently I get the whole list of data roles[] when toggleOpenEdit i would like the roles[0] and so forth to be shown only

I tried toggleOpenEdit(index) in the onclick but then it says expected 0 arguments got 1
... what am i missing??

```
 PARENT 
 const roles = [
 {role: 'Admin', created_on: '1/1/2019', status: "active", permissions: "add order, 
 update order" },
 {role: 'Admin II', created_on: '12/1/2019', status: "active", permissions: "add order, 
 update order, delete order, refund" },
 {role: 'Support', created_on: '2/1/2021', status: "active", permissions: "edit order, 
 update order" },
 {role: 'Support II', created_on: '10/15/2020', status: "inactive", permissions: "add 
 order, update order, some other thing" },
 {role: 'Owner', created_on: '1/1/2019', status: "active", permissions: "add order, 
 update order, change inventory, refund, delete, remove users" },
]


 export default function accounts() {
const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
const toggleOpenEdit = () => {  setOpenEdit(!openEdit)};

return (
          <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
      
            <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
              {roles.map((role, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                 <td className=" whitespace-nowrap  text-sm font-medium ">
                    <DotsVerticalIcon
                    onClick={toggleOpenEdit.bind(index)}
                    className={'text-gray-400 ml-2 h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-gray-500'}
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                  </td> <td className="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font- 
                 medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">
               {roles.role}
                  </td>
                  <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500"> 
              {role.created_on}</td>
                  <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500"> 
              {role.status}</td>
                  <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500"> 
              {role.permissions}</td>

                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
      
    <div className={"columns-1 mx-5"}>  
     ** child -> ** {openEdit ? <Edit roles={roles}/> : null }</div>
  </div>   
 
 </div>
 </Theme>
 )
}
```

Child component ____

```
  <div className=" mt-2 transform px-2 sm:px-0">
    <div className="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow- 
 hidden">
    
      <div className="relative grid gap-6 bg-white px-5 py-6 sm:gap-8 sm:p-8">
          <h2>Edit User</h2>
         

          <div className="-m-3 p-3 block rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50" >
            <p className="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">{roles.role}</p>
            <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{roles.created_on}</p>
            <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{roles.status}</p>
            <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{roles.permissions}</p>
          </div>
      
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i realized if i do this         {openEdit ? <Edit roles={roles[0]} /> : null }</div>
i will pass the first index back to the child but i need to make that work differently

Comment: Will you make a code example that focuses on your question? There is a lot of extra noise in your code here that has nothing to do with what you are asking. Please trim it down so that we can help you.

Comment: trimmed a bit out

Comment: Did you check if this code still actually works? I think `roles.role` should be `role.role`.

Comment: right now it returns a blank component. 
  ** child -> ** {openEdit ? <Edit roles={roles}/> : null }</div> 
^^ how will i get roles={roles} to just pass the one clicked when click (roles[0] or roles[4])

Comment: I was referring to `{roles.role}` in the middle of all the `<div>`s. I think this should be `role.role`, but that is a relatively trivial typo. See my answer below for some suggestions.

Comment: yeah that one is a typo

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is that you need to pass a single role to props with something like `roles[i]`. So that means you need to have a way to pass the correct index to use. It looks like you are trying to do so with `onClick={toggleOpenEdit.bind(index)}`, but `toggleOpenEdit` does not take any arguments, so `index` is just ignored here. You will need to find a way to fix this to keep track of which `index` to use. Most likely this will require state so that when the component is rendered again, it renders with the correct role.

Answer (score 1):

```
       const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(undefined);                    

               <DotsVerticalIcon
                onClick={(index) => setOpenEdit(index)}
                className={`text-gray-400 ml-2 h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-gray-500`}
                aria-hidden="true"
                />

 ** child -> ** { <Edit roles={openEdit ? roles.[openEdit] : {}}/> }</div>
```

Not really sure if this is the answer you are looking for but :

We pass the current clicked role from the roles.map( .... ) initiali it is undefined since we dont want to show anything on load  . And you dont need the .bind() this is used in class components

Comment: that doesnt quite work for me. i think i removed the parts where we toggle open a popover that should show the info of the item click on the table

Answer (score 0):

I took both of your answers and worked them together

I set the index separately and got it to work

```
    const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
    const [i, setI] = useState(Number);  
    const toggleOpenEdit = (index) => { 
      setOpenEdit(!openEdit)
      setI(index)
     };  

   {openEdit ? <Edit roles={roles[i]} /> : null }</div>
```

now our popover only shows the data for the item click on the table!